# C++ using same Index function for different Sort functions

Tags: c++

I created a small practice program for practicing sorting data that is read from a file. The problem I ran into is that when I want to sort a different, specific column (then 2nd column in this case), I get the cannot convert data type error.

My goal is to be able to find the median, min, and max of only that column. Now, I understand that it's a data type mismatch issue, but I was wondering if there was a way to get around it? Because otherwise I would have to create another minIndex function which seems rather inefficient.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void readScore(ifstream & fin, double & x, int & y, string & z);

double median(double arr[], int n);

void swap(int & a, int & b);
int minIndex(double k[], int size, int startIndex);
void selectionSortAll(double k[], int l[], int size);
void selectionSortY(int l[], int size);

struct XYZ
{
    double varx[4];
    int vary[4];
    string varz[4];
};

int main()
{
    double x;
    int y;
    string z;

    ofstream fout;
    ifstream fin;

    fin.open("struct fstream.txt");

    XYZ calcX;
    XYZ calcY;
    XYZ calcZ;

    double scoreSumX = 0;
    int scoreSumY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        readScore(fin, x, y, z);
        calcY.vary[i] = y;
        calcX.varx[i] = x;
        calcZ.varz[i] = z;
        cout << calcX.varx[i] << " ";
        cout << calcY.vary[i] << " ";
        cout << calcZ.varz[i] << endl;
        /*scoreSumX += calcX.varx[i];
        scoreSumY += calcY.vary[i];
        cout << "Current sum: " << scoreSumX << endl;
        if (i >1)
        {
            cout << "Current average: " << scoreSumX / (i + 1) << endl;
        }*/
    }

    cout << "" << endl;

    selectionSortAll(calcX.varx, calcY.vary, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << calcX.varx[i] << " ";
        cout << calcY.vary[i] << " ";
        cout << calcZ.varz[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << median(calcX.varx, 4);

    fin.close();
    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

void readScore (ifstream & fin, double & x, int & y, string & z)
{
    fin >> x >> y >> z;
}

double median(double arr[], int n)
{
    if (n % 2 == 0)
        return arr[n / 2];
    else
        return arr[n / 2];
}

void swap(int & a, int & b) {
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

int minIndex(double k[], int size, int startIndex) {
    int minI = startIndex;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < size; i++) {
        if (k[i] < k[minI]) {
            minI = i;
        }
    }
    return minI;
}

void selectionSortAll(double k[], int l[], int size) {
    int minI;

    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < size; startIndex++) {
        minI = minIndex(k, size, startIndex);
        swap(k[startIndex], k[minI]);
        swap(l[startIndex], l[minI]);
    }
}

void selectionSortY(int l[], int size) {
    int minI;

    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < size; startIndex++) {
        minI = minIndex(l, size, startIndex);
        swap(l[startIndex], l[minI]);
    }
}
```

The error occurs with the very last function, "selectionSortY", because the first argument "l" in this case is an **int** but the first argument in the function "minIndex" is a **double**. Would I have to just create another minIndex function for indexing different data types?

Oh and for reference, the input file looks like this:

```
634 423 qwerty
115 935 jkl
968 156 asdf
439 593 iopu
```

Thank you for your time and any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Edit: Just to clarify, the program works just fine without the "selectionSortY" function. "selectionSortAll" sorts the first two columns as intended.

Edit2: I'm new to programming, so please bear with me if I'm a bit slow to catch on or if I just straight up don't know what something is. Also for the actual assignment (much bigger than this so I didn't post it here), I'm somewhat limited on what I'm allowed to use since this is the first semester of a beginner course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a template:

```
template<typename T>
int minIndex(T k[], int size, int startIndex) {
    int minI = startIndex;
    for (int i = startIndex; i < size; i++) {
        if (k[i] < k[minI]) {
            minI = i;
        }
    }
    return minI;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10062eee9f4017fc)

---

As an aside, I would consider leaning more heavily on [<kbd>`<algorithm>`</kbd>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) and [STL containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) like [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) to accomplish your goal. [Finding the minimum element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element), [for example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a694561311262152).

Comment: I replaced it with this and it gives me a list of errors starting with "T" not being defined in the scope. Is there a specific way that I am supposed to incorporate this? Sorry I didn't mention but I am new to programming in general.

Comment: @BaloneyOs: I'm sorry, but you'll need to be more specific. Did you look at my Live Demo? How are you calling the function?

Comment: @BaloneyOs: You should be able to call it exactly as you were before; just replacing the `minIndex` function with the version I wrote.

Comment: Oh my bad, I took a more careful look at it and made the appropriate changes and now it seems to work for my purposes so far at least in this program. Going to test it in the actual program. Thanks so much!